# wxWidgets: Is there a makedirs function that creates more non-existing subdirs along the path?

Tags: wxwidgets

Having a path (here Windows) like c:\MyPath\where\ **the\part\of\it\does\not\exist**. Is there any function in wxWidgeds that creates all the missing (bolded in the example) subdirectories, or do I have to write some on myself?

(If you know Python, the `os.makedirs()` is the equivalent.)

Thanks,

Petr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the static function [wxFileName::Mkdir](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_name.html#ac2006b2fb30c0c0f11ef44560e1a62c7) and pass it the `wxPATH_MKDIR_FULL` flag.